# Using distinct() order_by() filter() altogether

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a query:

```
titles= Entry.objects.filter(created_date__gte=date_from,user__followed__follower=request.user).order_by('-created_date').values_list('title', flat=True).distinct()
```

It works fine except the distinct part which doesn't work and distinct("title") is not supported by the database I'm using. Performing set() on the query object without using distinct() brakes the order. The only solution I came up with is to append every title in a list and check if it already exists there, which probably is an overkill.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think perhaps `list(dict.fromkeys(...))` is what you want (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961425/5084488)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct They already denied not use all this methods at once.

Comment: Nice one thanks a lot. But I still wonder if there is any way to do it in one ORM.

Comment: @mattarello which database are you using Postgress or sqlite?

Comment: SahilDesai thanky you for the link I'm sorry I missed that.